# Parse.com Cloud Code synchronous swift func

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am having a problem with my application and parse.com in swift. I have tried to seperate all of the functions for parse into their own file as functions to be called by the controllers that need them.

Below is an example of the code

```
class func getUsersInNetwork() -> (users: [String??], names: [String],     profilePics: [String])? {
    var users: [String??] = []
    var names: [String] = []
    var profilePics: [String] = []

    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getUsersInNetwork", withParameters: [:])     {
        (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            var objects = response as! [AnyObject]

            for object in objects {
                var objectId: String?? = object.objectId
                var name = object.objectForKey("firstName") as! String
                var imgUrls = object.objectForKey("imgUrls") as! [String]

                users.append(objectId)
                names.append(name)
                profilePics.append(imgUrls[0])
            }
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error!)")
        }
    }
    return (users, names, profilePics)
}
```

The problem is when I call this function it returns empty lists because the parse call is not done yet. How can I fix this. Is there a way to call this with a synchronous request?

Comment: [PFCloud does have a synchronous request method](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFCloud.html#//api/name/callFunction:withParameters:).  Why not use that?

Comment: I wasn't able to get a response from that only an error

Comment: And your current implementation returns empty lists.  Why not try to figure out what the error is?

Comment: I think better advice would be to make your wrapper function asynchronous, also, giving it a block parameter declared the same way as the parse function.  For a hint, set your cursor on `callFunctionInBackground` in your source file, right click and select "Jump to definition".

Comment: No I doesn't return an error. It only returns if there is an error. Basically the things you can get back from callinbackground are error, and response. For the callfunction it is just error.